# python multiple import performance and standards compliance

Tags: python, import, coding-style, python-import

The Python wiki about `import` statement [performance](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead) states:

> Although Python's interpreter is optimized to not import the same module multiple times, repeatedly executing an import statement can seriously affect performance in some circumstances.

Take the two snippets below:

Snippet 1:

```
from my_module import A
from my_module import B
from my_module import C
```

Snippet 2:

```
from my_module import A, B, C
```

Which is "better" in terms of:

- coding standards compliance
- performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is micro-optimising at best. `my_module` is imported into Python just once, in both versions; there is no performance difference to speak of.

The only difference is that Python will execute the `IMPORT_NAME` bytecode 3 times in snippet #1, versus just once for snippet #2; you get two cache checks after the initial import in #1. As this code is only ever going to be executed *just once* this is **not** something you'd worry about. After all, your module with these lines in it is also cached.

The *repeatedly* part applies to code that *in a loop* executes imports, not top-level-of-a-module code.

What is left is the [Python styleguide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports should usually be on separate lines, e.g.:
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
>  import os
>  import sys
> ```
>
> No:
>
> ```
>  import sys, os
> ```
>
> It's okay to say this though:
>
> ```
>   from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
> ```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I figured that this is micro optimisation, but I asked here to "double check". Shame my question is getting downvoted. I will delete it if it continues to get downvoted.

Comment: @JosvicZammit: Unfortunately, now that your question has an upvoted answer, you can no longer self-delete your question.